# Can we straightly send to printer from VisualForce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, method, printable

Do we have a native way to print from visualforce itself?

I know there is Javascript print method Browser.Print() .

But our requirement is to directly send to printer, I'm not sure if we can access local printers through visual-force, but at least to get the default one, and print using single click without having to select a printer. Curiously searching on it.

Any help here would be great. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/784656/Printing-in-one-click-I-dont-want-print-setup-dial - Strictly a JS problem. Would have to be done from browser...

Comment: At least a Salesforce plugin could have done this like they do have outlook, etc. plugins. a probable intallable windows, mac extension to access local devices.

Comment: For the time being, found a solution called PrintNode, which runs as a service in local machine. Tried this one and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you are asking is something close to IoT (Internet of things). There have been some integrations between the printer and Visualforce (or any hosted page). However, there we also need to use Javascript but that is different than `Browser.print()` because it is Javascript API to support various specific printer functions.

One of the Printer I can remember is of Epson brand which provide Javascript API to connect with your local printer attached with same network and accessible through a protocol which some thing look like `https://localhost:4434/epson/label/printrequest`.

I recommend you to talk with that printer's vendor and they would suggest you the way to connect.